# In second batch, exclude workers from first batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

How do I run a second batch on a HIT but ensure I have a new set of workers?  I want to make a small change to the HIT and start a new batch, but I don't want any of the workers who participated in the first batch to participate in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to add assignments to your existing HITs (you can do this easily through the RUI), which will exclude workers who have already done those HITs.

But, before you do that, you'll need to change the HITs, which is more difficult (but relatively easy through the API using a ChangeHITTypeOfHIT operation for title/description/duration/qualification changes). If you need to change the Question parameter of a HIT (the actual displayed content of the HIT) or the amount it pays (reward), then you need to create new HITs and send them out as a new batch.

To prevent workers from redoing the HITs you can either put a qualification on the HIT and assign all of your current workers to a score below that level.

Or, you can put a note on the HIT saying that duplicate work will be unpaid. If you do this, you should include a link on the HIT that takes workers to a list of past workerids so that they can check whether they've already done the task.

Comment: This is going deeper than I hoped.  Let's see if I understand the basic point.  If I run a second batch using the same HIT with no changs, it will automatically exclude workers from the first hit.

Comment: Second, if I modify the contents of the HIT (not create a new HIT), will it still exclude workers from the first HIT?

Comment: Regarding your first question, if you add assignments to a HIT, only new workers will be able to do it. This doesn't apply to a whole batch though. Say one worker (#1) did one of ten HITs you posted and one worker (#2) did the other nine. If you add assignments to all of those HITs, #1 would be able to do the nine they hadn't done and worker #2 would be able to do the one they hadn't done. And new workers could do all of the HITs.

Comment: On your second question, what do you mean by modify contents of the HIT? If you change the Question property, then it is not the same HIT, in which case you would need to use one of the methods described in my answer.

Comment: Well, the UI gives you essentially two choices.  You can create a new HIT or you can edit an existing HIT.  I would like to assume that if you edit an existing HIT, it would keep the same database id and be treated, for purposes of excluding prior workers, as the same HIT.

Comment: Are you referring to the "edit" buttons here: https://requester.mturk.com/create/projects? If so, that's not going to work the way you're hoping. MTurk does not really provide the ability to "edit" HITs once they're created.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that button.  So, then, "edit" is really creating a new HIT?

Comment: Basically MTurk is a web app. Then the UI is a sort of weird wrapper for that, which provides additional features. The Create/Edit screen you're looking at is in that weird wrapper. So "edit" means editing a Question template, which is then submitted to an actual HIT...meaning you're not editing the HIT but the instead the template, which could be used to create new HITs.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2018:

You don't need to modify the content of the HIT anymore.

Instead, you assign a qualification to the previous participants in a csv sheet.

Then, in the new HIT, you set as requirement that this qualification "has not been granted".

Detailed explanation at the bottom [here](http://www.josephjaywilliams.com/mturk/how-to-prevent-workers-from-participating-in-experiments-multiple-times/creating-auto-grant-qualifications-to-exclude-workers-from-participating-multiple-times?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates) and step-by-step procedure describe in this [pdf](https://experimentalturk.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/excluding-workers-from-previous-studies-using-excel.pdf).